# error of syntax in the cmd parameters

Tags: c, syntax-error, command-line-arguments

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *operator[][10] = { {"(",")","[","]","->","."},
                    };

int main(int argc,int *argv[])
{   
    int len = sizeof(operator)/sizeof(operator[0][0]);

    for( int k = 1 ; k < argc ; k++ )
        printf("%s ",argv[k]);

    printf("\n");               

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < 6 ; j++ )
        {
            for( int k = 1 ; k < argc ; k++ )
                if( !strcmp( argv[k],operator[i][j]) )
                    printf("%s",operator[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

after compiled , I want to test if "->" is work,so I use command `test.exe ->`,and it turns out a error of syntax.But when I change the command to `test.exe "->"` it works. I wonder if it's about order syntax.
p.s my OS is win7 and I use Dev-cpp.
thanks for any help.

Comment: You are indexing the `operator` array out of bounds. The outer loop goes from zero to one, so you're indexing `operator[1]` which is out of bounds. You actually don't need that extra "dimension", use just e.g. `const char *operator[] = { "(", ... };`

Comment: it's just a part of code.I simplified it,so it appeares that fault.thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` has special meaning to the command prompt, it's used to redirect output to a file. You need to quote it to treat it literally.

BTW, I think this line in your program is wrong:

```
int len = sizeof(operator)/sizeof(operator[0][0]);
```

It should be:

```
int len = sizeof(operator)/sizeof(operator[0]);
```